# adding javascript script from handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have been following an excellent tutorial for creating a shopping cart in `node.js`
But I have hit a snag, and I have read and re-read the code and can't see what I have done wrong.

Basically I have an `hbs` file called: `checkout.hbs` and at the bottom of the page I have these 2 entries:

```
<script type="/text/javascript" src="javascripts/checkout.js"></script>
<script type="/text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

I have a public folder in my project with a javascripts folder and a `checkout.js` file in there.

However when I click the submit button it seems to ignore the javascript file and go straight to the post. I tried putting some random code in the `checkout.js` file to see if it crashed, but it didn't which suggests its not even trying to use the script and I am not sure why.

checkout.hbs - **should get checkout-form using id in checkout.js**

```
<form action="/checkout" method="post" id="checkout-form">
```

checkout.js

```
var $form = $('#checkout-form');
$form.submit(function (event) {
```

Comment: can you actually check your Net tab and see if it actually reads the file? not just getting 200 response, but also has the actual contents you expect

Comment: sorry the Net tab? what's that?

Comment: try $form.submit(function (event) { event.preventDefault(); console.log("stop here")}

Comment: I don't know what I did but it works when I changed the script tag to:

Comment: <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

Comment: <script src="javascripts/checkout.js"></script>

Comment: the Network communication tab of your browser's development tools. please don't ask questions on stackoverflow until you've checked all of the places where your browser and/or server display information about what's going on

Comment: Anyone know what I did to make it work?! I am certain I tried that before... so strange!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change:

```
<script type="/text/javascript" src="javascripts/checkout.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="javascripts/checkout.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
<script type="/text/javascript"
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript"
```

OLD VERSION:

try not using the protocol to links (even outside of your site)

```
https://js.stripe.com/v2/
```

can be written as

```
//js.stripe.com/v2/
```

and the browser will use the same protocol for the link as the one in the browser's address bar

Comment: Thank you. I'm still a bit confused why changing 
<script type="/text/javascript" src="javascripts/checkout.js"></script>

Comment: to <script src="javascripts/checkout.js"></script> fixed it?

Comment: /text/javascript is wrong. the actual type is without the first slash, just text/javascript or application/javascript should be used. because /text/javascript is invalid, the browser ignored the script, just as if you'd use text/plain. when you removed the type attribute, it defaulted to javascript

Comment: now write your own solution as an answer and accept it

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to this. Much appreciated.